# Update Gradle references to include maven local jars (libGDX & Tween Engine)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, libgdx

I follow this steps for setting External dependencies:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle

(section: External Dependencies Examples >> universal-tween-engine using maven)

After do that, i check maven repo direcory and the files are there:

C:\Users\Admin.m2\repository\aurelienribon\tweenengine\6.3.3

[image]

Executing gradlew bat for rebuilding the project returns no errors:

[image]

I'm missing something because in Eclipse didn't see the references to Tween engine:

[image]

And obviously, if i try to add a reference to Tween Engine on my code i get an error:

[image]

How can i set up a new reference on existing gradle project, using libGDX for using Tween Engine in this case?

Comment: Did you run `gradle --refresh-dependencies` and `gradle eclipse`? Also try to select all projects in eclispe, rightclick them and do a Gradle -> refresh all

Comment: @noone you are right...selecting all projects and running context menu Gradle >> Refresh dependencies fixed the dependency problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want me to write that as an answer, or are you going to delete the question?

Comment: @noone, yes, your comment solved my question...so..yes it was an answer. Thanks agains. Cya

Comment: I wrote it as a proper answer and hope you will accept it, so it won't be listed as unanswered anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did everything correct, but just adding the dependencies will not refresh the dependencies in eclipse.

You have to mark all related projects in eclipse, right click them and perform a `Gradle -> Refresh Dependencies`. Depending on what exactly you have changed, you might even need to do a `Gradle -> Refresh All`.

This will update the dependencies in eclipse and you will find the needed classes.