# LibGDX + Gradle + Maven Reference to Tween Engine can't be found

Tags: eclipse, maven, import, gradle, libgdx

I am working from Eclipse Luna on Windows 7 and am trying to import the Universal Tween Engine through a local Maven repo.

I am encountering the same error as listed in this question:

[Update Gradle references to include maven local jars (libGDX & Tween Engine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314348/update-gradle-references-to-include-maven-local-jars-libgdx-tween-engine)

I reasoned that I am in the same ditch as the images reflect my setup based on what the user shared.

The answer and suggestions, though, did not resolve the issue.

When this failed, I decided to try the other option listed in: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine, specifically the FileTree Dependency method, but also to no avail (as well as looking over this response [why dont i have universal tween engine when setting up LibGDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083263/why-dont-i-have-universal-tween-engine-when-setting-up-libgdx)).

Running the `gradlew --refresh-dependencies` works fine, build successful.

Running the `gradlew eclipse` cmd returns this output:

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':android:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find aurelienribon:tweenengine:6.3.3.
     Required by:
         game:android:1.0 > game:core:1.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Thoughts? If you need more information, I can supply it. I am just not sure what all might be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. For whatever reason I couldn't get the Maven repo to work, even though it had worked for a previous project.

Initially, the copying-the-exported-folder-into-/libs trick didn't work for me.  What I did was copy the jar files in the tween-engine-api-6.3.3 folder and paste it directly into the /libs folder.  Then it worked!  I think the wiki could clarify this step.

Comment: I ended up adding the jar as an external jar and just decided to avoid the headache. Thank you for answering!